# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO' when installing email package

Tags: python, email, pip

I have seen suggestions telling me to make sure my Python version in email is up to date. I have already done that. After pushing to email master, I ran the install command, but it gives me the following errors.

```
pip3 install email
```

my error

```
Collecting email
  Using cached email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.e
xe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ylwazhye\\email_b18cbf4a683f4c258a4e857
fe71d3291\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-install-ylwazhye\\email_b18cbf4a683f4c258a4e857fe71d3291\\setup.py'"'"';f =
getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) el
se io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().
replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'
"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-eg
g-info-hmjq9ggs'
         cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylwazhye\email_b18cb
f4a683f4c258a4e857fe71d3291\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pa
ckages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylwazhye\email_b18cbf4
a683f4c258a4e857fe71d3291\email\parser.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

Comment: to upgrade a package you need to pass the --upgrade flag in pip

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this 

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install [this package](https://pypi.org/project/email/#files). As you can see from the list of the files on its page it hasn't been updated since the 2007 year and the latest supported Python version is 2.5.

Perhaps you don't need this library. There is a built-in [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) package available for the Python 2.7 and Python 3.5+.

Comment: my python version is 3.6.2

Comment: @pradeepruwan Yes, so it is incompatible with the third-party [email](https://pypi.org/project/email/#files) package. Just use the built-in `email` package without installation.